# how to open a folder in terminal in nautilus (with root privilege) ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, sudo

Under the nautilus without root privilege, we can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or right click to bring the popup manual to open a specific folder in terminal.

However, it is troublesome to get sudo in the terminal every time to access the files in the folder. So, I just open the nautilus with root privilege but I find the 'open in terminal' option just disappears in the pop up manual by right click on the folder.

I can get the 'open in terminal' option by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> but no response after clicking this option. Can someone help to get the fix?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do this. You want to be careful running your file manager as root, and only do this for these specific tasks that require root access. You certainly are not needing root permissions for your daily work on the computer, so the fact that root permissions are not immediately available in the graphical user interface can be seen as a sound implementation.

If your main concern is that you find it tedious to type `sudo` each time, then you can open a prompt with root permissions with the command

```
sudo -i
```

This gives you a shell prompt as root user (your ~ becomes /root). Again, exit this prompt (`exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) this prompt as soon as you do not need the root permissions anymore.